# How can I make a form use content data type "x-www-form-urlencoded" instead of "multipart/form-data"?

Tags: expressionengine

I have a form submitting with {exp:channel:entry_form} on Expression Engine 2.3. I'm upgrading a site from EE1.7 to EE2.3, and the form sends correctly on the old version using content data type "x-www-form-urlencoded" (ie. standard data type for posting form data; check out the Network tab in Firebug to see the content data type in the header information).

When using the entry_form tool in EE2.3, however, it sends using content data type "multipart/form-data", and the tool is not gathering the data correctly. Admittedly I don't know what's going on with the back-end, but I do know that the form data is not sending correctly.

How can I ensure that the form data is sending correctly?

Thanks a lot,

Paragon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{exp:channel:entry_form}` is [deprecated](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/entry_form.html). Use the [SafeCracker module](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/safecracker/index.html) instead.

Aside from that, "not sending correctly" is pretty vague - what errors are you encountering specifically?

Lastly, the current version of EE is version 2.4. You should be using that instead of 2.3.

Comment: Thanks for the link. You should know, however, that I am not getting any errors. I've also explained the nature of the flow of information which is causing issues (content data type).

Currently, 2.4 is not an option until I successfully update to EE2.3. There are constraints that are out of my hands.

Comment: Like Derek said you'll need to rewrite the pages that are using the old entry_form tags to use safecracker. The old tag may partially work (ie not show any errors) but it wont handel certain field types correctly. Safecracker FTW.

Comment: Thanks @PhilipZaengle! I'm just holding out on accepting this answer until I implement it (should be today) and I know I don't have any unresolved related issues.